How to show a modal when clicking on an image?
What am I doing wrong here?
Main code:
library(shiny)

ui <- bslib::page_navbar(
  title = 'Layout App',
  nav_panel(
    title = "First",
    fluidRow(
      class = 'first_page_grid',
      
      nameUI('one') 
      
      )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   
  nameServer('one')
 }

shinyApp(ui, server)

The module code:
nameUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
  
    tags$img(
      src = paste0('img/Word1/', list.files(path = 'www/img/Word1')[1]),
      
      style = "width:50%; height:50%; object-fit:cover;object-position: top;
            cursor:pointer;",
      onclick = sprintf("Shiny.setInputValue('%s_img_click', '%s')",
                        ns('img_click'), list.files(path = 'www/img/Word1')[1])
    )
    
  )
}

nameServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      
      observeEvent(input$img_click, {
        req(input$img_click) # Garante que o valor não está vazio
        showModal(modalDialog(
          title = "Clicked Image",
          paste("You clicked:", input$img_click),
          easyClose = TRUE
        ))
      })
      
    }
  )
}

The idea: The user clicks on the image and the image shows up as a modal on the screen.
I don't know how to use javascript properly, and I believe that this is the reason of the problem.
How do to this?

Your problem is that the onclick is setting a value at input$`one-img_click_img_click`  but your observer is listening for input$one-img_click.
You should use
onclick = sprintf("Shiny.setInputValue('%s', '%s')",
                              ns('img_click'), list.files(path = 'www/img/Word1')[1])

